# To attach suffix to name column in a table so that it may be read in R

Tags: r, awk

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Gene    U2803   U2823   U2840   U2841   U2862   U2872   U2897   U2982   U2991   U2994   U2998   U2999   U3001   U3007   U3012   U2980
A1BG-AS 7.3159  9.3802  10.77   8.701   13.6066 8.3253  9.0556  9.8801  9.0776  11.2029 7.61    10.8403 9.2378  12.1697 9.7482  5.5327
A1BG    7.4715  5.2955  10.2275 6.3606  10.1463 5.9968  6.2673  8.6119  6.153   6.7903  4.0843  13.0875 6.8167  8.3186  6.7643  5.14
A1CF    0   0   0   0   0.0026  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0037  0
A2LD1   1.776   1.125   1.3508  1.2489  2.1252  2.1057  1.0177  1.6063  1.0053  0.9571  1.4972  1.3998  1.0935  2.4737  1.2063  1.7788
A2ML1   0.1024  0.092   0.0473  0.071   0.1227  0.2047  0.2481  0.1089  0.0499  0.1381  0.057   0.0953  0.0433  0.0651  0.0598  0.0434
A2M 5.4296  0.1688  2.4767  0.2507  0.5087  4.2835  2.2989  8.6027  3.1126  0.4565  0.167   2.9066  3.195   0.942   5.8904  6.7635
A4GALT  0.2918  11.5673 4.9554  0   1.6693  1.6301  0.4985  2.4444  0.6217  1.4638  3.2648  0.5773  3.1071  7.651   0.4068  5.133
A4GANLT 0   0   0   0   0.0575  0.1018  0   0.0422  0   0   0   0.0257  0.0276  0   0   0.0288
AAA1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
AAA1    18.789  24.8681 29.8037 33.3986 37.8269 24.4719 21.1101 26.9985 21.9897 25
```

If you notice two genes in column1 have same names, AAA1 and A4GALT. How can I add suffix to these genes so that it is not recognized as duplicate names while reading this table in R.

A small example in R or awk will be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: R should be able to handle reading this in without a problem. If you want to change the values in the "Gene" column to have unique values even when duplicated, you can try the `make.unique` function.

Comment: What suffix do you want ?

Comment: Suffix like _ (underscore) followed by a number would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk adds a new number to each occurence of the gene.

```
awk 'a[$1]{$1=$1"_"a[$1]}{a[$1]++}1' file
```

Hope it helps :)

That previous example was bugged.

This actually works as described

```
awk 'a[$1]{a[$1]++}NF&&a[$1]{$1=$1"_"a[$1]}!a[$1]{a[$1]++}1' file
```

The reason the first one didn't increment was due to an unforseen side effect of renaming $1, $1 was already changed when it reached the increment so the new value was being incremented , not the original.

Anyway it works now :)

P.s if someone knows how to reduce this let me know :)

Comment: What do you mean ? What tab separation ?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do as a post-read-in step in R.

Imagine we have a file like "x" below.

```
x <- tempfile()
cat("A 1 2\nB 3 4\nC 5 6 13\nA 7 8\nB 9 10\nA 11 12\n", file=x)
```

You've tried to read it in like this, but ran into problems because of duplicated `row.names`:

```
read.table(file = x, row.names = 1, header = FALSE, 
           fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # Error
# Error in read.table(file = x, row.names = 1, header = FALSE) : 
#   duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Read it in with the `row.names` as a column first, and then work from there.

```
temp <- read.table(file=x, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
temp
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  A  1  2 NA
# 2  B  3  4 NA
# 3  C  5  6 13
# 4  A  7  8 NA
# 5  B  9 10 NA
# 6  A 11 12 NA
```

FYI, a `matrix` *can* have duplicated `rownames` (but I don't really suggest this):

```
temp1 <- as.matrix(temp[-1])
rownames(temp1) <- temp[, 1]
temp1
#   V2 V3 V4
# A  1  2 NA
# B  3  4 NA
# C  5  6 13
# A  7  8 NA
# B  9 10 NA
# A 11 12 NA
```

Instead, look at one of the functions that can be used to create unique names, such as `make.names` or `make.unique`. The latter seems more appropriate for this scenario.

```
make.names(temp$V1, unique=TRUE)
# [1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "A.1" "B.1" "A.2"
make.unique(temp$V1, sep="_")
# [1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "A_1" "B_1" "A_2"
```

You could incorporate it as follows:

```
rownames(temp) <- make.unique(temp$V1, sep="_")
temp$V1 <- NULL
temp
#     V2 V3 V4
# A    1  2 NA
# B    3  4 NA
# C    5  6 13
# A_1  7  8 NA
# B_1  9 10 NA
# A_2 11 12 NA
```